# 3 valve shower allowing flow to tub and shower

Tags: bathtub

I have a price pfister 3 handle shower (circa mid 70s) that when set to shower also lets water out of the tub spout. . When set to tub only, flow is completely blocked to shower head. I have replaced the seat washer and the valve seat with no improvement.  There are no other replacement parts on this valve. I applied air pressure from the shower nozzle down to the diverter to test if the diverter was sealing and i could hear no bypassing air through the valve. When pulling the valve back out i can physically see where the washer has compressed against the seat.

Any idea why i cant get the divertor to block flow to the tub?

Comment: In the shower mode there is back-pressure at the diverter because the shower head is has a flow restriction, but when the tub spout is selected there is no pressure because the spout offers no resistance.  What kind of diverter is this: in the spout or in the wall.

Answer (score 1):

You (almost certainly) need to replace the "diverter washer". In the picture below you can see it on the middle valve assembly (the diverter valve), it's a white plastic disc that sits between the backside of the valve stem bib area and the valve body:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A poorly sealing diverter will leak out the spout in the shower mode, but not leak the other way because in the shower mode there is back-pressure at the diverter because the shower head is has a flow restriction, but when the tub spout is selected there is no pressure because the spout offers no resistance.

What kind of diverter is this: in the spout or in the wall.